# Spring - How to commit inside forEach

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have the following code:

```
private void sendList(List<Data> myData) {

  myData.forEach(x -> {
    sendData(x);
  })

}

@Transactional
private void sendData(Data myData){
  //do some changes in myData object and inserts into table
}
```

Currently, it commits after the insert is complete for every Data object.

But, I would like to commit every 500 records.

Is possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you don’t need a loop to save the data. Use `saveAll` instead. (It’s the power of crud).

Secondly, you should add **batching**. By default it isn't switched on. Therefore you have to add some params to *application.properties*:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=500
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
```

The 1st property tells Hibernate to collect inserts in batches of 500. The `order_inserts` property tells Hibernate to take the time to group inserts by entity, creating larger batches.

[Source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-batch-inserts)

Comment: thank you so much for you answer. I will implement the way you suggested and soon I mark as answer if works